# Changing column widths

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I currently created a side-by-side two column div at 50% each div. I'm trying to figure out how to make the left div 70% and the right div 30%.

Also, in addition to the 2 column divs. If I wanted to create a 4 col divs of 25% each and a five column div of 20% each. How would I do this?

```css
.container-2col {
  clear: left;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: none;
}

.container-1col {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  right: 50%;
  background: none;
}

.col1 {
  float: left;
  width: 46%;
  position: relative;
  left: 52%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.col2 {
  float: left;
  width: 46%;
  position: relative;
  left: 56%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-2col">
  <div class="container-1col">
    <div class="col1">
      <p>Delicious and crunchy, apple fruit is one of the most popular and favorite fruits among the health conscious, fitness lovers who firmly believe in the concept of &ldquo;health is wealth.&rdquo; This wonderful fruit is packed with rich phyto-nutrients
        that, in the true sense, indispensable for optimal health. Certain antioxidants in apple have several health promoting and disease prevention properties, and thereby, truly justifying the adage, &ldquo;an apple a day keeps the doctor away.&rdquo;</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
      <p>Vegetables, like fruits, are low in calories and fats but contain good amounts of vitamins and minerals. All the Green-Yellow-Orange vegetables are rich sources of calcium, magnesium, potassium, iron, beta-carotene, vitamin B-complex, vitamin-C,
        vitamin-A, and vitamin K.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/huskydawgs/zhckr47h/3/

Comment: Not sure I follow, but what about changing `.col` width to 64% and `.col2` width to 28%? Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/zhckr47h/4/)? Since your left and right are currently each 46%, then the 64% and 28% are the same total (92%) but have a balance of 70:30 instead of 50:50.

Comment: "If I wanted to create a 4 col divs of 25% each and a five column div of 20% each. How would I do this?" - that's impossible, it's a 120% of width:)

Comment: 70% and 30% inside the 100% tag

Answer (score 2):

There are several methods for creating multi-column layouts with CSS Grid.

Here's one way, featuring the `grid-template-columns` property and flexible (`fr`) lengths.

```css
article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 75px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

article:nth-child(1) {
  grid-template-columns: 7fr 3fr;
}

article:nth-child(2) {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

article:nth-child(3) {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}

/* demo styles only */
article                 { margin-bottom: 2em; }
section:nth-child(odd)  { background-color: lightgreen; }
section:nth-child(even) { background-color: orange; }
```

```html
<article>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</article>

<article>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</article>

<article>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:inline-block` instead of `float`. This eliminates the need for your other `divs`. Remove the space in between elements by using `margin-right:-4px`. There are other fixes to this issue if you want to dig for them. `Float` has its place, but I find it causes more problems than it solves.

```
 .col1 {
    display:inline-block;  
    width: 30%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    margin-right:-4px;
    vertical-align:top;
    background-color:yellow;
    }
```

Just change the `width` accordingly for `col2`.

See JSfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/zhckr47h/12/

Comment: This can be applied endlessly to any number of  divs with any desired width

Comment: The one time I use float to resolve these issues is in combination with a set width on the float, and `overflow: hidden; width: auto;`on the non-floated element. This causes an unexpected formula where the browser actually gives you a perfect, separated, two-column layout (albeit, with non-synchronized heights) with no need to figure out percentage math.

Answer (score 0):

Without tweaking your code that much, this is easy to do. But first get rid of the floats and instead display inline-block and vertical-align:top.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a19umhon/)

```css
.container-2col {
  clear: left;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: none;
  margin: 0!important;
  padding: 0!important;
}
.col1,
.col2 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  background: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.col1 {
  width: 69.5%;
}
.col2 {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-2col">
  <div class="container-1col">
    <div class="col1">
      <p>Delicious and crunchy, apple fruit is one of the most popular and favorite fruits among the health conscious, fitness lovers who firmly believe in the concept of &ldquo;health is wealth.&rdquo; This wonderful fruit is packed with rich phyto-nutrients
        that, in the true sense, indispensable for optimal health. Certain antioxidants in apple have several health promoting and disease prevention properties, and thereby, truly justifying the adage, &ldquo;an apple a day keeps the doctor away.&rdquo;</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
      <p>Vegetables, like fruits, are low in calories and fats but contain good amounts of vitamins and minerals. All the Green-Yellow-Orange vegetables are rich sources of calcium, magnesium, potassium, iron, beta-carotene, vitamin B-complex, vitamin-C,
        vitamin-A, and vitamin K.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have set the width to 69.5% because body always has padding unless you explicitly remove it

Answer (score 0):

I have changed `left` and `right` properties with `margin`s for easier calculations. So the new widths for a 70-30 layout has to be: 70% - 4% (margins) = 66% and 30% - 4% (margins) = 26%.

```css
.container-2col {
  clear: left;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: none;
}
.container-1col {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: none;
}
.col1 {
  float: left;
  width: 66%;
  margin: 0 2%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.col2 {
  float: left;
  width: 26%;
  margin: 0 2%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-2col">
  <div class="container-1col">
    <div class="col1">
      <p>Delicious and crunchy, apple fruit is one of the most popular and favorite fruits among the health conscious, fitness lovers who firmly believe in the concept of &ldquo;health is wealth.&rdquo; This wonderful fruit is packed with rich phyto-nutrients
        that, in the true sense, indispensable for optimal health. Certain antioxidants in apple have several health promoting and disease prevention properties, and thereby, truly justifying the adage, &ldquo;an apple a day keeps the doctor away.&rdquo;</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
      <p>Vegetables, like fruits, are low in calories and fats but contain good amounts of vitamins and minerals. All the Green-Yellow-Orange vegetables are rich sources of calcium, magnesium, potassium, iron, beta-carotene, vitamin B-complex, vitamin-C,
        vitamin-A, and vitamin K.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```